# Select value from pick list into PHP variable

Tags: php, variables, select, picklist

I have a script that uses a selection value to select a year. I want to have the year determine which dataset to display in an adjacent table. I was given the following script. Clicking the word Homes should go to the main page for Homes.php. Selecting a value from the pick list should give data for that year.

```
<form action="homes.php" method="get">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color: #000;" onclick="GoTo('homes.php')">Homes</a>
<select name="saleyr" style="width:60px;" onchange="GoToTemplate('Homes',this.value);">
     <option value="2015">2015</option>
     <option value="2014">2014</option>
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
     <option value="2012">2012</option>
     <option value="2011">2011</option>
     <option value="2010">2010</option>
     <option value="2009">2009</option>
</select>
```

This is the code that calls the dataset. I want the 2015 below to be replaced by the selected value:

```
foreach ($neighborhood['Homes']['2015'] as $saleyr) {
```

Comment: I do have a form. just added that code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a form and by clicking submit send the selected value to server to handle it.

```
    <form action="http://homes.php" method="post">
    <select name="saleyr" style="width:60px;" onchange="GoToTemplate('Homes',this.value);">
         <option value="2015">2015</option>
         <option value="2014">2014</option>
         <option value="2013">2013</option>
         <option value="2012">2012</option>
         <option value="2011">2011</option>
         <option value="2010">2010</option>
         <option value="2009">2009</option>
    </select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
```

Comment: Sorry. I have a form. Just added the code above. Not sure how to place the year value into the variable where 2015 is showing in the foreach loop. ie. hard coding the '2015' into the loop pulls the correct data. I want a variable to pull the selected value and reload the table.

Comment: if you add the `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></form>` your seleceted value will be at the **$_POST['saleyr']** .  anchors aren't used for transfering data..